# How to use the registered activeX control at server side in an ASP or ASP.NET web page?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

If we write the `global.asa` file to access the object, then how do I access this object in an ASP page?

global.asa file (expanded here for readability):

```
<object 
    name="axGlobasys"
    id='axGlobasys'
    runat ="server"
    scope="application"
    classid='CLSID:0F01FC4F-CCBB-4bfd-8805-204D4ED49647'
    codebase='AxControlsGlobasys.cab#version=1,0,0,0'>
</object>
```

How can I access the activeX control through the web server?

Comment: what do you need exactly more than this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317392 ?

Comment: @DavidePiras: That link is irrelevant to the question, the question is about server-side usage of `<object>` not client-side.

Comment: @Davide Piras :i already try this but it's working at client side but not at server side

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `StaticObjects` collection on the object to which you defined the scope, ie above you specified application scope, so `Application.StaticObjects("axGlobalsys")` will retrieve this object.

I don't believe asp.net has a similar syntax.

Comment: can you please tell me this how to write this code inside the ASP page

Comment: You write what I put above. set myobj = Application.StaticObjects("axGlobalsys")